# How to prove the divergence of the sequence $(n!)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that
$(n!)^{1/n}$ tends to infinity as $n$ tends to infinity ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that 
$$
n!>\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}.
$$
This observation follows from writing out $n!$ as $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots2\cdot 1$ and taking half of the factors, those of size at least $\frac{n}{2}$.

Therefore,
$$
(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}>\left(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}},
$$
which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be any positive integer. $(n!)^{1/n} \geq (k(k+1)\cdots n)^{1/n} \geq k^{(n-k+1)/n}$ for $n >k$. Can you see from this that $(n!)^{1/n} \to \infty$?.